# Will a "Sandbox mode" mod get me banned or lead to any other repercussions?

Tags: mods, clash-of-clans

Will using a mod like [Sandbox Mod](http://gigaster.blogspot.com/2014/09/sandbox-mode-in-clash-of-clans-practice.html) get me banned or lead to any other repercussions?

Comment: I'd suggest you ask the game makers, we can only guess as to what they'd do if they found you cheating in this way. their terms of service quite clearly disallow mods.

Comment: Would "has anyone been banned yet, as far as anyone knows" be a better question?

Comment: The issue here is that we cannot assure you of the question. Those who do it can say then don't experience the problem, you do it and can get caught on the first try. Is it worth the risk?

Answer (score 2):

If Supercell finds out that you use that mod then yes, they will warn or ban you. You can read their Terms of Service here: http://supercell.com/en/terms-of-service/